Get only the unique editors of a file and not the inherited folder owner
I am trying to move files from a current folder that Person A has editor rights to a new folder that  Person B has editor rights.
I tried to do a .getEditors() on the files, and then move them to the new folder, but it brings Person A along with the other editors. Is there some type of sub-permission that I can access to only bring those unique file editors and not the folder owners where the files are currently?
UPDATE:
The first two editors show as me (the overall owner) and the folder owner, so I tried this loop to find additional editors in the array. It seems to work, but is there a better option?
function editorTest(){

  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Id of my target file");
  var childDSEditors = ds.getEditors();
  Logger.log(childDSEditors)

  for (e = 2; e < childDSEditors.length;e++){
    fileOnlyEditors = childDSEditors[e]
 
    Logger.log(fileOnlyEditors)
}}

SECOND UPDATE:
This didn't actually work, since I didn't realize that the owner is always shown first, and then any editors are show alphabetically afterwards. I am trying to only get the editors assigned at the file level (not the owner, which is me, as well as the classroom that has editor rights to the folder in which the file is residing). There is a list of possible classroom folder editors, so I am trying to compare the file editors to that list to remove them. Then, I will assign them editor rights to the new file in the new folder. Any thoughts would be great!

The following code return an array of editors, excluding the spreadsheet owner. It uses Array.prototype.filter.
function getEditors() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ownerEmail = spreadsheet.getOwner().getEmail();
  const editors = spreadsheet.getEditors().filter(editor => editor.getEmail() != ownerEmail)
  
  Logger.log(editors);
}

Regarding moving a spreadsheet to a folder:

You will need to use the Drive Service or the Advanced Drive Service
Nowadays, a Google Drive file can have only one folder as a parent.

Considering the above, you might have to refine your algorithm to handle the case of having more than one editor. One option might be to move the original spreadsheet to the folder corresponding to the first editor and create a copy for each other editor. Another option might be to create a file shortcut for the other editors.
Related

Moving Files In Google Drive Using Google Script


@TinaT I'm glad that this answer has been helpful to you. Please consider accepting it. Ref. What should I do when someone answers my question
